# Using dataframe in a class to filter results

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I've created a class to preprocess a document with pandas dataframes. However, I'm having trouble using filters within my class.  My code is below:

```
class Dataframe:
    def __init__(self, my_dataframe):
        self.my_dataframe = my_dataframe
        self.my_dataframe = self.filter_priv()

    def filter_priv(self):
        df = self.my_dataframe.copy()
        df = df[~(df.priv_id > -1) | ~(df.restriction_level > 0)]

df1 = Dataframe(df)

df
```

My output is always non filtered results.  My input file has 262,000 records, and with the filter, when called outside my class it successfully filters my df down to 11,000 records.  Any ideas why it does not filter in the class?

Comment: You don't return anything from `filter_priv`. Is that your intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing this *way* wrong. You're subclassing from dataframe, but then you're storing your data inside a special dataframe property. No bueno.

You should be subclassing if you want to have a class that quacks like a dataframe, but you want to add some other behavior that's not available.

If you want to subclass, you should be doing it like this:

```
class Dataframe(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Dataframe, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def filter_priv(self):
        return self[~(self.priv_id > -1) | ~(self.restriction_level > 0)]

# Not sure if you can create a dataframe from another
df1 = Dataframe(df)
```

But that's really probably not even what you want. It's probably better to just have:

```
def filter_priv(df):
    return df[~(df.priv_id > -1) | ~(df.restriction_level > 0)]

df1 = filter_priv(df)
```

Comment: But the OP is not subclassing a DataFrame. And in your example you are not subclassing a DataFrame, so `super` won't do as you describe.

Comment: Ah... I see that now (which also explains why I didn't subclass, since I just copy/pasted the code). Apparently I simply *assumed* that anyone creating a class called `Dataframe` would do so to subclass the pandas `DataFrame`, because why else would you create a class and name it nearly the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You're problem might be that you're using the variable "df" to initialize a Dataframe class, but the variable df hasn't been defined yet...